# Is code syntax highlighting turned on for Signal Processing?

Tags: feature-request, formatting, syntax-highlighting, code-formatting

Is code syntax highlighting turned on for Signal Processing?

The matlab code I posted in response to [What are high frequencies and low frequencies in a signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1036/what-are-high-frequencies-and-low-frequencies-in-a-signal/1038#1038) did not get [syntax highlighted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting). I posted the same code to Code Review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7188/matlab-code-demonstrating-use-of-fft-fast-fourier-transform), where it did get highlighted.

Comment: The subsequent request from 2021: [Can we get code highlighting turned on, please?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1731/58918)

Comment: I can't believe this question has over 10 years... It's switched on! 

Answer (score 7):

We can turn on code syntax highlighting if the community sees a need for it -- do you think many posts would benefit?

It's not a heavy dependency, but it is a minor one, so we'd want to make sure that it will benefit many posts not just a few.

Comment: Seriously, it's disabled?  With no explanation of why it's not working when I try umpteen different variations on the comment thinking that it's my fault that it's not working?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to ask a new question or to undig this one, but it seems like this feature is still not turned on, and I think it would be more comfortable if not useful for a lot of users.

Comment: +1 I'd like to see syntax highlighting because many of our users post code.

Comment: @AtulIngle Looking at it now. No idea why I didn't see this activity on Meta when it happened. Apologies for the delayed response.

Comment: @Florent Looking at it now. No idea why I didn't see this activity on Meta when it happened. Apologies for the delayed response.

Comment: syntax highlighting should be dependent on the language (like C or C++ or something else).  it shouldn't be dependent on who is posting the language.

Comment: Yes. Please turn **Syntax Highlighting** for DSP.SE. Code is one of the best way to express algorithm and should be promoted as 1st class citizen here.

Comment: Any progress on that? We really need to promote answers which includes code and hands on examples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be turned on now:

[image: Screenshot of question with C++ highlighting]