# How do we get syntax highlighting and MathJax turned on?

Tags: feature-request

Both have been asked for before, but neither has happened.  What do we do to get these turned on?

[Is code syntax highlighting turned on for Signal Processing?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/133/29)

[Can we have MathJax enabled in Meta?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1212/29)

Yes, DSP.SE is for signal processing theory questions, not coding questions, but good-fit questions still often use code examples, and it would be nice to have them highlighted.

Math formatting is even more appropriate on a theory-centric site.

Comment: I'll check in with Stack Exchange team and find out what the status on these is. I would be a little cautious about syntax highlighting, for the single reason that most code posted here is MATLAB, and MATLAB highlighting is pretty much broken on Stack Exchange. Anyway, I'll get back with some info soon.

Comment: MATLAB is certainly one of the dominant languages, but Python is also quite common and at least it can be easily highlighted.