# Can we get code highlighting turned on, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

This has been [asked before](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/is-code-syntax-highlighting-turned-on-for-signal-processing), but our site is currently not on the [list of sites where it's enabled.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314553/which-stack-exchange-sites-have-syntax-highlighting-enabled)

The suggestion on that last link is:

> If a topic isn't primarily focused on programming but could
> substantially benefit from a particular flavor of syntax highlighting,
> post a request on the site's per-site meta and link to some (10 or so)
> posts where highlighting would be helpful. SE staff will then evaluate
> the request and let you know the result.

So, here's a list of questions that might benefit from it:

- [Wrong result when realizing fixed-point biquad IIR filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78955/wrong-result-when-realizing-fixed-point-biquad-iir-filter)
- [Gaussian Blur For Entire Image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78944/gaussian-blur-for-entire-image/78947#78947)
- [Non-Uniformly Partitioned Convolution Implementation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78711/non-uniformly-partitioned-convolution-implementation)
- [How to implement a moving average in C without a buffer?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20333/how-to-implement-a-moving-average-in-c-without-a-buffer)
- [Python FIR Notch filter applied on both + and - frequency but only need + frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78816/python-fir-notch-filter-applied-on-both-and-frequency-but-only-need-freque/78821#78821)
- [Find the equivalent of this python remez specs in C++ remez or Matlab firpm](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78778/find-the-equivalent-of-this-python-remez-specs-in-c-remez-or-matlab-firpm)
- Plus just about any question tagged with [`c`](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c), [`c++`](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B), or [`matlab`](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab).

Comment: So who is responsible for turning it on?

Comment: @mhdadk The SO folks. We need this item to get more upvotes before it'll be considered.

Comment: +3141592 thumbs up for this! 

Comment: Might want to consider putting [meta-tag:status-review] so that [it's monitored by SE staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/241919).

Comment: @AndrewT. D'oh! Thanks for that. Done.

Comment: y e s ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, I don't see why not. Y'all should have syntax highlighting now.

Shout if you see any issues.